# Can I kick the counter in for loop (to skip some number of iterations)?

Tags: python, loops

I mean if we have a look at this:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print i
    if i == 5:
        i += 1
        #j = randint(6, 9)
        #i = j
```

Suppose, j occurred to be 1. I would like 6 to be skipped. Now the result is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7 ,8, 9. I want 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7 ,8, 9.

Please, don't offer 'continue' to me. j may be calculated on the run.

I can't catch the behaviour here. I study Python after Java. And I have modelled this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 5){
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly understandable for me (6 is skipped).

Could you comment on this behaviour of the Python loop?

Comment: I can't understand how you say continue can't work for you, when you have the exact equivalent of continue in the Java version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `for` loop is many other languages' `foreach` loop.  In that context, it should make sense: for each *x* in some collection, do something to each *x*.  You can rebind what `x` refers to within the body of the loop, but that doesn't do anything, since you're just making `x` point to a new object (and even if you do manage to mutate `x`, the `foreach` loop just merrily continues on to the next item, not caring what you just did to `x`).

So, you can hack it together with a `while` loop, as [in the linked thread in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450446/how-do-i-use-a-c-style-for-loop-in-python).  That's one way. (and really, a "c-style" `for` loop is just syntactic sugar for writing a `while` loop)

Or, you could write a [coroutine](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/).  Generators are pretty cool, and a coroutine is just a generator you can send values into - for example, if you wanted to tell `xrange` halfway through that it should iterate over some different numbers entirely:

```
def co_range(*args):
    _range = iter(xrange(*args))
    while True:
        sent = yield next(_range)
        if sent:
            _range = iter(xrange(*sent))
            yield

co = co_range(10)

for x in co:
    print x
    if x == 5:
        co.send((15,20))

0
1
2
3
4
5
15
16
17
18
19
```

obviously you could abstract this out further and send arbitrary iterables into your generator - so as you can see, coroutines are quite powerful, if a bit clunky in syntax.  This is *certainly* overkill for simple "I want to skip a number" but probably fits the bill for some more complex skip-to-12-then-maybe-go-back-to-4-but-then-give-me-15-through-20 type of logic.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense in Python because you iterate through an object. The current value of `i` is the next value in the iterator. The best solution would be to remove the values beforehand, but the correct solution to skip a data that is calculated on the fly is to use `continue`.

Comment: thank you. But how can I skip two or more iterations? No, continue can't help. Maybe I'll try while loop.

Comment: `while` loop is rarely the best solution in Python from my experience. You'll have to explain your problem in more details, because I can't see how a simple `if i == j: continue` would not work.

Comment: Because I want more than one iterations to be skipped. I need a jump. So, I have calculated the length of this jump. And I want to jump.

Comment: You said `j` is calculated on the fly. `for i in range(5): j = randrange(1,3); if i == j: continue` would work correctly. Please take the time to edit your question and explain exactly what is your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your question is a complete description of what you're trying to achieve:

```
 for i in range(0, 10).remove(6):
```

Comment: I assumed when OP said "j may be calculated on the run", he meant that `j` could be calculated during the iteration.

Comment: Could be -- it's not clear to me whether the commented-out code is part of the question (if it is, I don't know why the counter is being advanced with `+= 1`).  The `j` part isn't in the java example.  But, that's why I included my caveat.  Without a better explanation of the issue, the best I think we can do is produce the desired output.