# TCL like for loop in python

Tags: python

I am looking `for` loop similar to other languages PERL/TCL/C++ in python.

Like in TCL below is the for loop

```
for { set i 0 } { $i < $n } { incr i} {

#I like to increment i value manually too like
if certain condition is true then increment
set i = [expr i+1] # in some cases
print i
```

I there similar way in python too. In python i know below is the for loop syntax

```
for i in var1
#How to increment var1 index manually in some scenarios
```

Comment: replace `var1` in your example with `range(0, n, 1)`

Comment: @DaleWilson: It will increment by one each time. But if we want to increment based on conditions like some scenarios increment by 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a C-style for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450446/how-do-i-use-a-c-style-for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
for i in range(0, n):
 # Do something
```

Also, you could use:

```
i = 0
while i<n:
 # Do something
 i+=1
```

Comment: If we want to skip some iterations manually inside for loop can we do that

Comment: Yes, but you will have the next number.

Comment: Put if-statement where you need.

Comment: The theme here is "Use the right tool for the job!"   If the increment is uniform, use a `for`  If it needs to be customized, use a `while`

Answer (score 1):

Python's `range` function, called like `range(b, e, i)` will yield integers starting with `b` and ending at `e`, incrementing by `i` each time.

Comment: How to increment in if some conditions are true

Comment: Add an `if` block for each iteration. If the condition doesn't evaluate to True, you can use `continue` to move to the next iteration.

Comment: It sounds like, if you also want to be able to manually increment `i`, use a `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have that style of `for` loop, so use a `while` loop.

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    # ...
    if some_condition: # Extra increment
        i += 1
    i += 1 # normal increment
```

Comment: Yes while loop I am aware of. I thought there is something in the for loop that I am missing. Thanks for clarification