# How to translate these Java for loops to Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

These loops are for iterating through a 2D array backwards, but I am too green in Python, so can someone help? This is how I would write them in Java:

```java
for (int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for (int j = cols - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    int target = A[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are struggling with *this* you should really work through a couple of python tutorials for the next couple of days.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a C-style for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450446/how-do-i-use-a-c-style-for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code would look like in python:

```
for i in range(rows-1,-1,-1):
  for j in range(cols-1,-1,-1):
    target = A[i][j]
```

Comment: for (int ii = i; ii < rows; ii++) {
        for (int jj = j; jj < cols; jj++) {

Comment: And what would that look like?

Comment: for ii in range(i,rows): for jj in range(j,cols): I would suggest you to read a little bit about the range function [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/range)